# Bayes probability excercise

Tags: probability

Define: A:= baby alive , B:=woman has a caesarean section

$P(A)=0.98 , P(B)=0.15 , P(A|B)=0.96.$

Find $P(A|B^c)$

My solution:

$P(B^c)=1-0.15=0.85, P(A^c)=1-0.98=0.02$

By  Bayes's theorem exists: $P(A|B^c)=\frac{P(B^c|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B^c)}$

I have no idea how to deal with $P(B^c|A)$ , I tried to substitute $P(B^c)=P(B^c|A)P(A)+P(B^c|A^c)P(A^c)$ but It doesn't succeded.

Help please ?

Comment: You don’t need Bayes, just: $$P(A)=P(B)P(A\mid B)+P(B^c)P(A\mid B^c) $$ You know all the terms here except one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$\mathbb{P}[A \cap B^c]=\mathbb{P}[A]-\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]=0.98-0.15\times 0.96$$

Thus simply, your result is

$$\mathbb{P}[A | B^c]=   \frac{0.98-0.15\times 0.96}{0.85}$$

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive way to think about these types of problems. Think of a
very large number of pregnant mothers, normalized to $100$ for simplicity. $%
P(A)=0.98$ tells us that $98$ of the babies will survive and $2$ will die. $%
P(B)=0.15$ tells us that $15$ will have a c-section. $P(A|B)=0.96$ tells us
that $96$ percent of the c-section babies will survive, i.e. $0.96\ast
15=14.4$, and thus that $0.6$ of the c-section babies will die. In total, $2$
babies die, so $2-0.6=1.4$ of these must be among the non c-section babies.
The survival among non c-section is thus $(85-1.4)/85= 0.983\,53$